# Why are the colors of the svg desaturated in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, color, color-management, svg

I imported an svg (man illustration) and a png(lamp) from inkscape in blender.
And then I rendered it.

This is rendered using cycles[image]
This is rendered using Evee [image]

The colors in the cycles are accurate and just like inkscape but the colors in evee look washed out.
My problem is not the overlapping faces in cycles , I knew that this is going to happen but the colors in the evee are desaturated and not accurate.

Comment: Try scrolling to the bottom of your render properties tab and under _Color Management_ change the _View Transform_ from "Filmic" to "Standard".

Comment: It is already set to standard.

Comment: I got the error. I had to convert SVG to grease pencil from path. I forgot to do that. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.